# Validations at Clinetside using JQuery in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

these are my models.

```
public class Question
{

private string _questionNo;  
private string _questionText; 
private List<Option> _options;

public List<Option> Options
{
    get { return _options; }
    set { _options = value; }
}
public string QuestionNo
{
    get { return _questionNo; }
    set { _questionNo = value; }
} 
public string QuestionText
{
    get { return _questionText; }
    set { _questionText = value; }
}
```

}

public class Option
{

```
private string _optionText; 
private string _optionNumber; 
public string OptionText
{
    get { return _optionText; }
    set { _optionText = value; }
}
public string OptionNumber
{
    get { return _optionNumber; }
    set { _optionNumber = value; }
} 
}
```

these is my controller

```
   public ActionResult GetQuestion(int id,string gid)
    { 
        var vewmodel = ques.GetQuestion(Gid, Uid, id);
        return View(vewmodel);
    }
```

this is my view.

```
     @model mobilesurveys.mt.Models.Question  
     @{ ViewBag.Title = "Question"; }
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1>
    @Model.SurveyName</h1>
    </div>
   @if (@Model.QuestionType == 7)
   {   
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDropDown", "GetQuestion", Model))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <fieldset>
            <label class="select">@Model.QuestionText
            </label>
            <br />
            <select name="selectedObjects" id="selectchoice1" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="--select--">--Select--</option> 
                @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
                {

                    if (@item.IsAnswer == true)
                    {
                    <option selected="selected"  value="@item.OptionNumber">@item.OptionText</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <option  value="@item.OptionNumber">@item.OptionText</option>
                    }

                }
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        </p>
    }
    </div>
   }
```

so i am binding the optoins based on QuestionTypeId(RadioButtions,CheckBoxes,TextBox,Select). Now I want to validate the data at clientside. I am using Jquery Scripts.

How can i write the validations. any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at this

http://www.jacopretorius.net/2011/01/client-side-validation-in-mvc-3.html

Comment: i have seen those examples. but i cant define validation on model. it changes everytime. firtst time with select and next with checkboxlist and next some random type. I have List<options> in Question model. do we have any other way to define validation on IList<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods.
1.You can do this by adding annotation in the model class
add like this line in model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required"), StringLength(230)]
```

in this way add annotation above the variable where you want.

Or 
2.You can use jquery code to validate.
I am giving you the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SubmitForm").click(function (e) {
            var textContent = $("#TextContent").val();
            textContent = jQuery.trim(textContent);
            if (textContent == "") {
                alert("Content field cannot be empty.");
                $("#TextContent").focus();
                return false;
            }


        });
    });
```

In this way you can check field in jquery .
Reply me if you find any prob

Comment: You can use the jquery method to validate your control
chk it you will find it useful 
and reply me if u get any prob

Comment: hey. when the second view is loaded its not firing the events. actually i am redirecting to the same view with different paramteres. the scripts are executed perfectly only for the first view. any help.

Comment: i posted it as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243139/value-not-updated-to-textbox-in-jquery-of-mvc3-view